# is it possible to index a hidden field?

Tags: search

i have a newsletter content type which consists of a link to a file (pdf) and a summary field.  the idea behind the summary field is that it will contain a list of keywords and when a search hits one of these keywords the newsletter item (and so the pdf file) will be highlighted.

the issue is that i don't really want the summary text to be displayed, but if i set it as hidden in the display it doesn't seem to be indexed.

anyway that i can persuade drupal to index this field?

using 7.12 by the way if that's important.

Dave

Answer (score 4):

The best way should be implementing the search_api module , with this module you can index anything and set the importance of the indexed field .

Here is a screen cast that shows how to implement [here](http://vimeo.com/15556855)

Note that the screencast must be updated because facet_api works now without apachesolr

Enjoy!

Comment: Search API is a really powerful and flexible module. It seems a bit overkill if you only need it for a single field in a certain node type, but it will solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think displaying the field and hiding it with css should do the trick.

Comment: Most likely this will work, but it's so _ugly_. Surely there is an api or some such for controlling the index content?

Comment: @Letharion: Sure, this not a really nice way, I agree. If you insist on calling it *ugly*, go ahead. However, I cannot agree on the downvote (which I assume is yours) since it means "This answer is not useful". This is the only answer in a month, and it's at least useful as a quick workaround. Please provide a better answer if you think this isn't good enough.

Comment: I just saw 28 and thought it was from yesterday. You have me convinced. :)